# Jquery.empty() not allowing to select item in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQUERY

I am trying to dropdown list item however I am unable to select item in dropdown list if I use JQUERY.EMPTY to clear dropdown list on click

```js
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function() {
            var opt = ["AP", "BP", "KP", "CS", "gh", "kol", "op"]
            $.each(opt, function(i, val) {
                $("#test").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(i).html(val)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="test">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r0d4xby6/ try this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This your proper solution. Your problem was that you were calling empty() on dropdown click, but when you select options it gets cleared again and refilled because that also counts as dropdown click. Therefore I have put an if which check if select was clicked, and if yes empty it, otherwise don't (if option is actually clicked).
I believe that's what you wanted.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").click(function(e){

    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.attr("id") == "test")
    {
        $(this).empty();
        var opt=["AP","BP","KP","CS","gh","kol","op"]
        $.each(opt,function(i,val){
        $("#test").append(
        $('<option></option>').val(i).html(val)
        );
        });

    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="test">
<option value="0">--Select--</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function() {
            $("#test").empty();
            $("#test").append($("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>"));
            var opt = ["AP", "BP", "KP", "CS", "gh", "kol", "op"]
            $.each(opt, function(i, val) {
                $("#test").append(
                    $("<option>"+val+"</option>")
                );
            });
        });
    });
```